# Which one is more efficient? $el.append(newView.render().el); or $el.append(newView.render().$el);

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Consider the following code snippet.

```
var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

    collection: new SomeCollection(),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty();
        this.collection.each( function (modelInCollection) {
            var newView = new AnotherView({ model: modelInCollection });
            this.$el.append(newView.render().el);
        }, this);
});
```

Would it be more efficient (memory, computational) to replace

```
this.$el.append(newView.render().el);
```

with

```
this.$el.append(newView.render().$el);
```

? Which one is the more elegant way and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one - `this.$el.append(newView.render().el);` would be more efficient because the underlying code for append() takes either a DOM node or a jQuery element, but eventually the jQuery element needs to be converted to a DOM node anyway because append() will finally use appendChild() which requires a DOM node.

**Performance Tests:**

So it seems it would be a micro-optimization at best.  Running jsPerf tests, appending either a DOM node or jQuery object are essentially the same, with results always within the margin of error.

http://jsperf.com/append-jquery-object-vs-append-dom-node